# profiling specific method with devpartner

Tags: c++, visual-c++, profiling, devpartner

I use devPartner to profile the performance of some C++ code. Is there a way to profile only a specific funcion, or remove a specific function from the profiling ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify /nmignore:: in the project settings under C/C++ additional command line options.

Function name can be the full function name, Start of function followed by * or *some pattern * for a contains clause.

So /nmignore:*:main would exclude main that is included in any file
/nmignore:main.cpp:myfunc* would exclude all functions that begin myfunc in main.cpp only
/nmignore:*:*std::* will exclude all std:: namepspace functions in all files.

Instrumentation happens between compile passes C1 and C2 so all functions are already inlined from the headers into the source files. Be careful of the wild cards as you may exclude more then you plan on.

Comment: Mark is the subject-matter expert on compile time instrumentation for DevPartner Studio.

Comment: As one other person mentioned and I meant to add to this you can compile your full program with instrumentation and then recompile just the one module / file you are interested in with performance or coverage instrumentation. Now this works pre VS2010 but VS2010 and 2012 use MSBuild and once you toggle the instrumentation settings all files are marked dirty and everything will be recompiled.  Sorry but that is just theg way things are with how we have to interface with MSBuild.

Comment: @Mark sorry for the late answer. I tried tu use /nmignore as you suggested, but with no result. Here is what I did : with visual studio 2010, under C++ > Command Line > Additionnal Options, I added /nmignore::readDXF (the function I don't want to profile). This function is part of a library, so I also added the /nmignore option to my test project. The problem is that I see no difference, the function readDXF is still profiled.

Comment: You are missing the "*" all files portion in your /nmignore directive. It should be  /nmignore:*:readDXF. I would also put a * before and after readDXF as it may get mangled and not ignored so  /nmignore:*:*readDXF* for your ignore. Hope tha helpst

Answer (score 0):

To some extent.  DevPartner instruments code for error detection, coverage or for performance, and it is possible to exclude certain namespaces, certain source files and perhaps even specific functions, from instrumentation.  There is even a way to exclude STL through its namespace 'std'.  Without the instrumentation, you get no profiling.

The build option required to prevent instrumentation from happening is '/nmignore', which has a number of possible parameters.  I don't use it myself, so I will have to get the details from the guy who takes care of the compile-time instrumentation code (my specialty is the back end of BoundsChecker).

Answer (score 0):

I had some luck compiling the full program without any instrumentation, then turning instrumentation on and recompiling just a single file.  That was for leak detection, not profiling, though.